# URP - Weird visual artifacts in Unity 2020.1.15f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started up a new URP project with everything pretty much default.

When I first loaded in a scene I noticed some weird shading issues. There were two concentric circles that were shaded in a way that it seemed like a depth of field effect. I wasn't sure how to get rid of them, so I moved on.

I got a basic first person controller and discovered more strange artefacts as I started walking around weird line imperfections within the grids and such, and the weird depth of field of effect I found in the scene view carried over into the game.

I've tried to searching around to find out if anyone else has had this problem before me, but I couldn't find anything. I've also tried to change post processing settings as well as some basic lighting settings. Nothing seems to fix the issue.

This video shows the issue a little more closely: *[URP Artifacts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXjsb_4C8lI)*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it by just creating a new project that did not derive from the URP template. Then I just manually converted it to URP.

I don't know why this happened when I was using the template. I don't know why this works. Probably it has something to do with the initial settings that come with the template, but that is just conjecture.